# Storing a string array in application settings

Tags: c#, application-settings, event-listener, arrays, stringcollection

I have a string array of information that I need to pass from one user control to the other. The application settings contains a `System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection` datatype for such cases. But since I need to use my array in a specific order, does a string collection help? Apart from that is it even a good idea to save such parameters in the application settings or is there a better way of passing these arguments around the program? I have used `EventListeners` in the program as well but passing arguments from one user control to the other seems less convenient with them.

Comment: A collection is always ordered (apart from those which implement `ISet<T>`, `IDictionary`).

Answer (score 2):

`StringCollection` is ordered in the way you inserted, so that would be sufficient for you.

As a tip: you can edit the `Settings.settings` file to change the data type of any field:

```
<Setting Name="Setting" Type="System.String[]" Scope="User">
  <Value Profile="(Default)"></Value>
</Setting>
```

Be advised that the type you define must the XML serializable!